# How to commit model instances and remove them from working memory a few at a time

Tags: sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have a pyramid view that is used for loading data from a large file into a database. For each line in the file it does a little processing then creates some model instances and adds them to the session. This works fine except when the files are big. For large files the view slowly eats up all my ram until everything effectively grinds to a halt.

So my idea is to process each line individually with a function that creates a session, creates the necessary model instances and adds them to the current session, then commits.

```
def commit_line(lTitles,lLine,oStartDate,oEndDate,iDS,dSettings):
    from sqlalchemy.orm import (
            scoped_session,
            sessionmaker,
    )
    from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
    from pyramidapp.models import Base, DataEntry
    from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension
    import transaction

    oCurrentDBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
    engine = engine_from_config(dSettings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    oCurrentDBSession.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine

    oEntry = DataEntry()
    oCurrentDBSession.add(oEntry)
    ...
    transaction.commit()
```

My requirements for this function are as follows:

1. create a session (check)
2. make a bunch of model instances (check)
3. add those instances to the session (check)
4. commit those models to the database
5. get rid of the session (so that it and the objects created in 2 are garbage collected)

I've made sure that the newly created session is passed as an argument whenever necessary in order to stop errors to do with multiple sessions blah blah. But alas! I can't get database connections to go away and stuff isn't being committed.

I tried separating the function out into a celery task so the view executes to completion and does what it needs to but I'm getting an error in celery about having too many mysql connections no matter what I try in terms of committing and closing and disposing and I'm not sure why. And yes, I restart the celery server when I make changes.

Surely there is a simple way to do this? All I want to do is make a session commit then go away and leave me alone.

Comment: Please readd the Exception message you get. It is a clear indicator of what is going wrong.

Comment: @SaschaGottfried: No exception message. RTFQ: everyhting grinds to a halt as all the ram is used up and the computer starts frantically paging. The ram usage can be observed so I observed it. Logic: Too much memory is being used => too many things using memory at one time => solution is to remove stuff from memory. Seriously, I'm happy you tried to help and all but sending people on wild goose chases because you don't actually know the answer or have any sensible idea of how to get to the answer is not a useful thing at all for anybody.

Comment: In first version of this question you had a InvalidRequestError. If Python is not raising that anymore, what have you changed until now?

Comment: It was an illustration of a failed attempt to fix the initial problem. It was not in itself a symptom of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried a bunch of things and, although using SQLAlchemy's built in functionality to solve this was probably possible I could not find any way of pulling that off.

So here's an outline of what I did:

1. seperate the lines to be processed into batches
2. for each batch of lines queue up a celery task to deal with those lines
3. in the celery task a seperate process is launched that does the necessary stuff with the lines.

Reasoning:

1. The batch stuff is obvious
2. Celery was used because it took a heck of a long time to process an entire file so queuing just made sense
3. the task launched a separate process because if it didn't then I had the same problem that I had with the pyramid application

Some code:

Celery task:

```
def commit_lines(lLineData,dSettings,cwd):
    """
    writes the line data to a file then calls a process that reads the file and creates
    the necessary data entries. Then deletes the file
    """
    import lockfile
    sFileName = "/home/sheena/tmp/cid_line_buffer"
    lock = lockfile.FileLock("{0}_lock".format(sFileName))
    with lock:
        f = open(sFileName,'a') #in case the process was at any point interrupted...
        for d in lLineData:
            f.write('{0}\n'.format(d))
        f.close()

    #now call the external process
    import subprocess
    import os
    sConnectionString = dSettings.get('sqlalchemy.url')
    lArgs = [
                'python',os.path.join(cwd,'commit_line_file.py'),
                '-c',sConnectionString,
                '-f',sFileName
        ]
    #open the subprocess. wait for it to complete before continuing with stuff. if errors: raise
    subprocess.check_call(lArgs,shell=False)
    #and clear the file
    lock = lockfile.FileLock("{0}_lock".format(sFileName))
    with lock:
        f = open(sFileName,'w')
        f.close()
```

External process:

```
"""
this script goes through all lines in a file and creates data entries from the lines
"""
def main():
    from optparse import OptionParser
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from pyramidapp.models import Base,DBSession

    import ast
    import transaction

    #get options

    oParser = OptionParser()
    oParser.add_option('-c','--connection_string',dest='connection_string')
    oParser.add_option('-f','--input_file',dest='input_file')
    (oOptions, lArgs) = oParser.parse_args()

    #set up connection

    #engine = engine_from_config(dSettings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    engine = create_engine(
        oOptions.connection_string,
        echo=False)
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine

    #commit stuffs
    import lockfile
    lock = lockfile.FileLock("{0}_lock".format(oOptions.input_file))
    with lock:
        for sLine in open(oOptions.input_file,'r'):
            dLine = ast.literal_eval(sLine)
            create_entry(**dLine)

    transaction.commit()

def create_entry(iDS,oStartDate,oEndDate,lTitles,lValues):
    #import stuff
    oEntry = DataEntry()
    #do some other stuff, make more model instances...
    DBSession.add(oEntry)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

in the view:

```
 for line in big_giant_csv_file_handler:
     lLineData.append({'stuff':'lots'})

 if lLineData:
            lLineSets = [lLineData[i:i+iBatchSize] for i in range(0,len(lLineData),iBatchSize)]
            for l in lLineSets:
                commit_lines.delay(l,dSettings,sCWD)  #queue it for celery
```

Comment: Yes. Post as much code as possible. Then I do not need to guess about the context.

Comment: @SaschaGottfried: The context is explained sufficiently but here is some code

Comment: Answer will take time and is going to illustrate the solution around the concept explained in http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/faq.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow - as Sergey recommended. These scripts can handle any load. Big difference to your approach is repeated flushing and committing by commiting using the SQLALchemy Session itself via Session.commit(). No use of transaction.commit() in offloaded scripts as this a concept related to SQLAlchemy integration into pyramid.

Comment: Look at function 'test_sqlalchemy_orm' going for the SQLAlchemy ORM approach as you want to use your models.

Comment: Added another answer. Your feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new session for each line of your large file is going to be quite slow I would imagine.

What I would try is to commit the session and expunge all objects from it every 1000 rows or so:

```
counter = 0

for line in mymegafile:
    entry = process_line(line)
    session.add(entry)
    if counter > 1000:
        counter = 0
        transaction.commit()  # if you insist on using ZopeTransactionExtension, otherwise session.commit()
        session.expunge_all() # this may not be required actually, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/We4XGX2CYX8
    else:
        counter += 1
```

If there are no references to DataEntry instances from anywhere they should be garbage collected by Python interpreter at some point.

However, if all you're doing in that view is inserting new records to the database, it may be much more efficient to use SQLAlchemy Core constructs or literal SQL to bulk-insert data. This would also get rid of the problem with your ORM instances eating up your RAM. See [I’m inserting 400,000 rows with the ORM and it’s really slow!](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/faq.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow) for details.

Comment: Thanks Sergy, for some reason that didn't solve my problem (there must be some secret references hanging around that I cant find) but it was a good read. Going down to using plain ol sql isn't really ideal because I would have to write a lot of it. I posted my solution as an answer...

Answer (score -1):

You are just doing it wrong. Period.

Quoted from [SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it)

> The advanced developer will try to keep the details of session,
>   transaction and exception management as far as possible from the
>   details of the program doing its work.

Quoted from [Pyramid docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/quick_tutorial/databases.html#analysis)

> We made the decision to use SQLAlchemy to talk to our database. We also, though, installed pyramid_tm and zope.sqlalchemy.
>
> Why?
>
> Pyramid has a strong orientation towards support for transactions.
>   Specifically, you can install a transaction manager into your app
>   application, either as middleware or a Pyramid "tween". Then, just
>   before you return the response, all transaction-aware parts of your
>   application are executed. This means Pyramid view code usually doesn't
>   manage transactions.

My answer today is not code, but a recommendation to follow best practices recommended by the authors of the packages/frameworks you are working with.

References

- [Big picture - Using Thread-Local Scope with Web Applications](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#using-thread-local-scope-with-web-applications)
- [Typical error message when doing it wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769841/sqlalchemy-sessions-error)
- [Databases using SQLAlchemy](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/quick_tutorial/databases.html)
- [How to use scoped_session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#unitofwork-contextual)

Comment: hmmm... TMI. I'll mark this correct if you edit stuff to answer only the question. For example, it would be safe to assume I know how to define models and commit them so the first link doesn't contain any relevant information.

Comment: ok... what part of http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/#getting-started is relevant considering that working models classes and views are already in place and the only problem is too many model instances in one place? That entire document is irrelevant unless there is some footnote buried somewhere about the fun thing the debugtoolbar does which is sortof relevant. It seems like a bit of a shotgun approach to answering questions. "Here, have loads and loads of info, your answer is in there somewhere". The answer is in there, can you point it out? I'll give you points

Comment: having a shorter commit_line function would be an obvious solution if this was not the case: "For large files the view slowly eats up all my ram until everything effectively grinds to a halt". I want to create a session, create some model instances, add instances to the session, commit those to the database, get the session and instances out of ram, rinse and repeat.

Comment: I can not make it easier for you. Please read my completely rewritten message carefully. The suggested solution is not to make commit_lines shorter, but to keep database engine and session setup code out of it.  This is my last edit. Good luck.

Comment: your solution is what I tried first. Exactly. I don't think you read the question properly but I edited it to explain better what I am after. Having a single session and allowing the pyramid to commit it through its usual mechanisms does not address the problem at all. Even a little bit. If you trust that my requirements are what are required then I need, as specifically stated, to NOT "establish a single Session, associated with the request, etc." In other words your answer is to close my eyes to circumstance and solid hardware imposed limitations (8Gb ram is simply not enough)? No can do

Comment: Best practices are nice. I stick to them whenever possible. But there is no hard and fast rule for this stuff. SQLAlchemy is simply not designed for use with hideously large datasets. Period. So to MAKE SQLAlchemy do what I want it to instead of what it wants to I NEED to move away from the norm. Hardware limitations can be overcome through use of properly thought out algorithms. Sometimes it makes sense to do exactly what the textbook says but sometimes it is worth being able to compensate for the limitations of the tools you use in order to achieve your goals

Comment: Challenge: Make a pyramid view that including a forever loop in which you create a new model instance and add it to the session. Find a way to, using sqlalchemy's best practices and whatever textbooks you like, make your ram never run out. Get a system monitor and look at what is actually going on. Do not simply redirect the view to itself or any of that sort of stuff because then you wont be emulating the problem you are trying to solve. If you don't know where to start in solving a problem try solving a simpler version of it instead of saying the question itself is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Encapsulate CSV reading and creating SQLAlchemy model instances into something that supports the iterator protocol. I called it BatchingModelReader. It returns a collection of DataEntry instances, collection size depends on batch size. If the model changes overtime, you do not need to change the celery task. The task only puts a batch of models into a session and commits the transaction. By controlling the batch size you control memory consumption. Neither BatchingModelReader nor the celery task save huge amounts of intermediate data. This example shows as well that using celery is only an option. I added links to code samples of an pyramid application I am actually refactoring in a [Github fork](https://github.com/saschagottfried/todopyramid).

BatchingModelReader - encapsulates csv.reader and uses existing models from your pyramid application

> get inspired by source code of [csv.DictReader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csv.dictreader#csv.DictReader)

could be run as a celery task - use appropriate task decorator

```
from .models import DBSession
import transaction

def import_from_csv(path_to_csv, batchsize)
    """given a CSV file and batchsize iterate over batches of model instances and import them to database"""
    for batch in BatchingModelReader(path_to_csv, batchsize):
        with transaction.manager:
            DBSession.add_all(batch)
```

pyramid view - just save big giant CSV file, start task, return response immediately

```
@view_config(...):
def view(request):
    """gets file from request, save it to filesystem and start celery task"""
    with open(path_to_csv, 'w') as f:
        f.write(big_giant_csv_file)

    #start task with parameters
    import_from_csv.delay(path_to_csv, 1000)
```

Code samples

- [ToDoPyramid - commit transaction from commandline](https://github.com/indypy/todopyramid/blob/master/todopyramid/scripts/initializedb.py#L92)
- [ToDoPyramid - commit transaction from request](https://github.com/indypy/todopyramid/blob/master/todopyramid/views.py#L209)

Pyramid using SQLAlchemy

- [Databases using SQLAlchemy](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/quick_tutorial/databases.html)

SQLAlchemy internals

- [Big picture - Using Thread-Local Scope with Web Applications](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#using-thread-local-scope-with-web-applications)
- [How to use scoped_session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#unitofwork-contextual)