# celery eating all my ram

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, rabbitmq, celery

**Here's what I'm trying to achieve:**

- I have a pyramid view that puts a rather large task `task_1` in the default queue
- `task_1` does a couple of simple database things then adds `task_2` to the default queue a whole bunch of times with different arguments.
- `task_2` instantiates some stuff in the database

**Here is what is happening:**

All my ram is eaten up and my computer starts paging frantically. So frantically in fact that the keyboard doesn't work well enough to stop the offending process.

The question is: How do I fix this?

**Here is what I have done so far, some assumptions I'm making and what I intend to try:**

I wrote a small script to take snapshots of what is using the memory up since a whole lotta stuff is added to the queue - RabbitMQ is playing nice, while celery gradually increases its footprint so the problem is there.

My informative celery log shows tasks being completed so it isn't just one task going haywire.

As far as I can see, celery simply isn't releasing memory after a task is completed. I think this has to do with sqlalchemy simply because it sometimes does some funny things. Case in point I once had a celery task that added some stuff to the database via sqlalchemy which it did fine for a while but then life ended. I took the part of the code that dealt with the sqlalchemy and stuck it in an external script that the celery task launched as a self contained process and all my problems went away. It's kinda a mission to do that every time I want to interact with a database in a celery task though so I would much prefer not to go that route.

Currently I'm reading a bit more about how celery actually works but I think that if I periodically restart the celery worker that would do the trick. Am I on the right path? Or is there something simple and obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Celery eating ram? This must be Soviet-Russia.

Comment: Today I read again your older thread, where you describe similar problems (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425879/how-to-commit-model-instances-and-remove-them-from-working-memory-a-few-at-a-tim). Considering how you dealt with my suggestions, I hope you find some guys that help you solving a problem with your code and you share not a single line of it.

Comment: @SaschaGottfried: you clearly misunderstood the problem. You might as well have told me to check that my keyboard is plugged in.